# Error loading RubyGems plugin ，openssl.bundle (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am new to ruby. When I type any thing related to gem, error below will happen. why causes it  and how to solve the problem? Thanks!

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/chiang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.2.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/chiang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/chiang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/chiang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: "type any thing related to gem" what are you trying to do

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Things to verify...

- How did you install rvm
- hit `rvm notes` and check if it's installed properly
- `ruby -v`, check for the version of ruby present

If you find any issues here, uninstall rvm using `rvm implode` and also remove ruby. Refer to the [rvm installation guide](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) for the use of this command.

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

**OR** you can try the other way without removing the present rvm installation.

```
rvm get stable
rvm reinstall 2.0.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I follow the official guide to install the rvm. rvm  version is 1.24.1 (stable), ruby version is ruby 2.0.0p247. I have tried to reinstall ruby but it  does't work.

Comment: what is the o/p of $ rvm list

Comment: I implode rvm and reinstall ruby again, it works! Thank U for your help!

Comment: For Debian and Ubuntu this is the only way I've found to solve the error. Thanks a lot

Comment: `rvm reinstall ruby` just worked for me in my case. Rails project was working fine before on the same machine. But for some reason it started complaining about this issue.

Answer (score 44):

The following worked for me.

```
brew rm openssl
brew cleanup openssl
brew install openssl
rvm reinstall ruby
```

Apparently `brew update` or `brew upgrade` breaks the Ruby runtime which is what caused the error for me.

Comment: The other answer did not help, but this did.

Answer (score 16):

To whoever having this problem with `rbenv`, I solved it reinstalling openssl and upgrading rbenv, then reinstalling ruby:

```
brew reinstall openssl
brew upgrade ruby-build rbenv
rbenv install 2.2.10 # or whatever version you're using it
```

Comment: I solved it by reinstalling ruby too.
rbenv uninstall <version> and then 
rbenv install <version>

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you already installed the right package aka `brew install/reinstall openssl` if not - do it.

Another **Solution** (In case your package is installed) - Might be that your package is not referenced to the right endpoint version, you have multiple versions of the same package (on this use-case openssl package) and your rvm is not finding it event though it's installed.

Run list of the package versions and switch to the right one.

**example:**

```
brew list  --versions openssl

/* Output:
openssl 1.0.2s
openssl 1.2
openssl 1.3
*/

brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
```

Answer (score 0):

Landed on this post in August '21 on Mojave using rbenv with this error:

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
Reason: image not found - /.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin17/digest/md5.bundle
```

Found an answer that worked for me on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65494858/5070253)

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
ln -sfn /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0/1.0.2t /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

(first command finished in ~5 minutes)

Coming from this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86)

Comment: Thank you, worked for me Dec '21 with Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

Downgrading `libssl-dev` helped to me:

`sudo apt install libssl-dev=1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.4`

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789556/cant-install-ruby-2-6-6-via-rvm-error-running-rvm-make-10-on-macbook-pro)