# All gem commands fail with "cannot load such file" errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run any `gem` command, I get this message:

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin 
"/home/thiago/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/yard-
0.8.2.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- 
rubygems/doc_manager (LoadError)
```

In this case, I run a simple `gem --version`. I'm using gem version: 2.6.8.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try reinstalling the ruby. This is many times caused by updating of ruby and the likes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely your installation of Ruby 2.4.0 is broken. First make sure it's installed:

```
$ rbenv versions
```

It should also have an asterisk next to it:

```
* 2.4.0 (set by /home/thiago/.rbenv/version)
```

If everything looks correct, I'd recommend uninstalling and reinstalling 2.4.0. If you still can't run `gem` commands, you might need to reinstall `rbenv` as well.

See also: a [related question for RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092600/error-loading-rubygems-plugin-openssl-bundle-loaderror).