# Can't install ruby 2.6.6 via rvm, error running '__rvm_make -10' on macbook pro m1

Tags: rvm, ruby-2.6

While installing the ruby 2.6.6 I'm getting this error:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -10'
please read /home/.rvm/log/1642694273_ruby-2.6.6/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I've tried to reinstall rvm but this changes nothing.

Other ruby versions are installed just fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`rvm install 2.6.6 --with-out-ext=fiddle` worked for me

Comment: I'd been wrestling `rbenv`, swapped out for `rvm`, and of course was finding more road blocks. Your solution helped so much to get me unblocked and to get the version of Ruby I needed installed. Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you share why this works and what this option does?

Comment: Can you explain what "--with-out-ext=fiddle" does and how you found out about it. Dream, divine inspiration, or whatever. 

It doesn't work for me, so I suspect I'll have to replace fiddle with something else.

Comment: out of everything, this worked! Thanks

Comment: Did not work for me unfortunately with my "Error running '__rvm_make -j8'". M1 MBPro, Ventura 13.0.

Answer (score 4):

downgrade `libssl-dev` with:

`sudo apt install libssl-dev=1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.4`

check the solution in this issue: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5209#issuecomment-1134927685

Comment: Thank you so much man... After thousands of different failed attempts, this simple action worked for me...

I tried several options, including:
  "rvm pkg install openssl";
  "rvm install 2.6.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr";
  "rvm install 2.6.3 --with-out-ext=fiddle";

But yours worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

MacOS 13.3.1  try this:

```
export rvm_configure_flags="--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1v/bin/"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1v/lib/pkgconfig"
```

then install again

```
rvm install 2.7.2
```

Comment: Thank you. it's worked for me.
My error "Error running '__rvm_make -j12'". System Ventura 13.0, M2.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click Terminal from the Application/Utilities folder, Get Info, tick the "Open using Rosetta" box.
2. Uninstall Homebrew
   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"`
   `rm -rf /opt/homebrew/*`
   `sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew`
3. Reinstall Homebrew
   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
4. Restart terminal
5. Check Homebrew is working fine: `brew doctor`
6. Reinstall openssl: `brew install openssl`
7. Install Ruby: `rvm install 2.5.3` Or any version

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have "Error running '__rvm_make -j8'", M1 MBPro, Ventura 13.0, make.log file's last few lines: 

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__mh_execute_header", referenced from:
      _rb_dump_backtrace_with_lines in addr2line.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
make: *** [libruby.2.6.dylib] Error 1
ln -sf ../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin22/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.1.h include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin22/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.1.h
+__rvm_make:0> return 2`

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Says something like this.
5 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [vm.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 warning generated.
12 warnings generated.
24 warnings generated.
14 warnings generated.
2 warnings generated.
+__rvm_make:0> return 2

Comment: Didn't work for me either. "something wrong with LDFLAGS"

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone, none of the posted solutions worked on my intel MacBook Pro.  `brew doctor` however did warn my developer tools were out of date.  Uninstalling and reinstalling those allowed me to return to using RVM as normal:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC rbenv install "your version"
```

Answer (score 0):

Mac M2 Pro, Ventura 13.4 works for -j10, all other methods didn't work

brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@3

rvm install 3.0.2

brew install --ignore-dependencies openssl@3